# ¿Cómo modificar el atributo href mediante condicionales?

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con archivos de texto en formato JSON y tengo un elemento del objeto que a veces puede quedar vacío según el contexto de lo que se vaya a poner (va a contener una url de un sitio web o puede quedar vacío) y el elemento es

```
...
"enlaceEXTERNO":"",
...
```

así está en el html:

```
<a href="#" id="enlaceEXT"></a>
```

en el javascript donde cargo el objeto estoy poniendo lo siguiente

```
if (datos.enlaceEXTERNO != "") {
    document.getElementById('enlaceEXT').href = datos.enlaceEXTERNO;
} else {
    document.getElementById('enlaceEXT').href = "#";
}
```

pero obviamente esta mal la el código que se encuentra adentro de la sentencia `else`, **¿Cómo puedo hacer que el atributo `href` pueda obtener el valor de '#' que se utiliza para que no se dirija a otra ventana o en otras palabras que quede deshabilitado?**

También estoy dispuesto a indicarle a la etiqueta que se remueva mediante el javascript cuando se encuentre vacía el elemento del JSON

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Quieres asignar a `href` el valor `#` cuando `datos.enlaceEXTERNO` esté vacío o quieres obtener `#` de `datos.enlaceEXTERNO` ¿? ¿Por qué dices que el `else` está mal? ¿qué es lo que está mal en él? Cuando hay un problema, explica el problema, no digas simplemente *hay un problema* o *esto está mal*.

Comment: mira como tengo el código y cuando le ejecuto en consola como tengo el elemento de JSON vacío me indica que no se puede implementar cambios al enlaceEXT y obtener el valor que se encuentre grabado si tengo noción de como hacerlo, en sí lo que quiero es asignar al  ``id="enlaceEXT"`` es ese signo para que se quede en la misma ventana

Comment: El área de abajo es para respuestas, si quieres agregar datos aclaratorios a la pregunta pulsa en [edit] para ello. Yo sigo sin entender qué es lo que tienes en el HTML y qué es lo que quieres lograr. Me parece que el problema es no saber explicar el problema. Sugiero que uses el [método del patito de goma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_depuraci%C3%B3n_del_patito_de_goma) para exponer tu duda en esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

hasta el momento una opción que encontré fue quitarle el `else` después del `if`

```
if (datos.enlaceEXTERNO != "") {
    document.getElementById('enlaceEXT').href = datos.enlaceEXTERNO;
}
```

o se puede poner `remove()`

```
if (datos.enlaceEXTERNO != "") {
    document.getElementById('enlaceEXT').href = datos.enlaceEXTERNO;
} else {
    document.getElementById('enlaceEXT').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola si quieres que el link este deshabilitado y que se quede en la misma ventana, usaría **javascript:void(0)** en reemplazo al **#**.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="enlaceEXT"></a>
```

Y el javascript quedaría así.

```
if (datos.enlaceEXTERNO != "") {
 document.getElementById('enlaceEXT').href = datos.enlaceEXTERNO;
} else {
 document.getElementById('enlaceEXT').href = "javascript:void(0)";
}
```